# I am trying to run a powershell command from batch script / command prompt but I keep getting error

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

Below is the singe line command I am trying to run from command prompt.

```
powershell -command "Get-Date (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_reliabilityRecords -filter \"sourcename = 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'\" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select @{LABEL = 'date';EXPRESSION = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.timegenerated)}} | select -first 01).date -format yyyyMMdd | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\winupdatelatest.txt"
```

Error :
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type
"System.DateTime"."
At line:1 char:10

- Get-Date (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_reliabilityRecords -filter "sour ...
- ```
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

Thank for your help

Comment: So what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is your command, where each line is a new parameter:

```
powershell 
-command 
"Get-Date (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_reliabilityRecords -filter "sourcename
= 
'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |select @{LABEL = 'date';EXPRESSION = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.timegenerated)}} | select -first 01).date -format yyyyMMdd | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\datelatest.txt"
```

Basically, your problem is that because you use " ... " ... " ... " some part of the command is seen as a parameter and other part is not.

The easiest solution by far is to put everything inside a .ps1 file and just use:

```
powershell -file myfile.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

But if you really have to use this command, then use """ as substiture for one ". Your command would become:

```
powershell -command "Get-Date (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_reliabilityRecords -filter 
"""sourcename = 'Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient'""" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
|select @{LABEL = 'date';EXPRESSION = {$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.timegenerated)}} 
|select -first 01).date -format yyyyMMdd | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\datelatest.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, i try above but i am getting below error
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: Corrected my answer.